# How to pass Err.Raise errors up the stack

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

Suppose Proc1 calls Proc2, which calls Proc3.

In Proc3 I generate an error with Err.Raise and handle the error. So far so good, but now I exit Proc3 and control passes to Proc2, which due to the error in Proc3 should branch into cleanup and exiting. However, Proc2 doesn't know an error occurred in Proc3, so instead it proceeds normally. Same with Proc1.

What's a good way to handle that? All I can think of is checking for each possible Err.Raise error in Proc3's error handler, and raising the same error again there. And then doing the same in Proc2. But that doesn't seem to work, and it seems like there must be a better way anyway.

Comment: Sounds like Proc3 should not handle the error. Proc2 should.

Comment: You can make your routines into functions that return a Boolean to indicate success. Thus the calling code can check the result and exit if required.

Comment: Once you've handled an error, it's handled: it won't bubble back up the call stack unless you re-raise it from within your handler.  Exactly how you would structure your code to deal with this would depend on the impact of the error on the rest of the process.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you have error handling enabled, your code will immediately jump to the next line in the method where error handling is enabled.  As such, when you have error handling enabled at a higher level in the call stack, this means your code will immediately jump to the point right after the method call in the **lowest** method in the call stack where error handling is enabled.

For example (assume all code in this answer starts with a call to `Proc1`):

```
Sub Proc1()
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox 1
    Proc2
    MsgBox 6
End Sub

Sub Proc2()
    MsgBox 2
    Proc3
    MsgBox 5
End Sub

Sub Proc3()
    MsgBox 3
    Dim x As Integer
    x = CInt("x")
    MsgBox 4
End Sub
```

This will display "1", "2", "3", then "6" because of the error it encounters in `Proc3`.  If the error weren't present, it would, of course, display "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6".

Now, you can enable error handling separately at a lower level in the call stack.  For instance, if I add `On Error Resume Next` to `Proc2` like this:

```
Sub Proc2()
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox 2
    Proc3
    MsgBox 5
End Sub
```

Then my output becomes "1", "2", "3", "5", "6".  Note the addition of the "5" because now the error handling is occurring in `Proc2` and continuing on the next line.